# Let $G$ be a connected cubic graph of order $n>4$ having a girth $3$. Determine $\chi(G)$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected cubic graph of order $n>4$ having a girth $3$. Determine $\chi(G)$.

I think $\chi(G)=3$, so I need to prove that $\chi(G) \geq 3$and $ \chi(G) \leq 3$.

The first part is easy assuming the contrary that $\chi(G) =2$ this contradict to the fact that $G$ has girth $3$, so $\chi(G) \geq 3$.

For the second part, cn I just use the definition of chromatic number and say $\chi(G)$ can't be more than $3$ because $\chi(g)$ is the minimum number used to color vertices of $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that doesn’t really make sense. Each vertex of $G$ is adjacent to $3$ other vertices, so in principle you might easily need $4$ colors. You can, however, use [Brooks’ theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem).

Comment: the Brook's theorem say $\chi(G) \leq \Delta(G)$. We only know that the smallest cycle in $G$ has length $3$. How does this say anything about $\Delta(G)$?

Comment: @Diana: $G$ is cubic, so *every* vertex has degree $3$.

Comment: ahhhhh, how could I forget that part, thanks.

Comment: @Diane: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Using Brook's theorem $\chi(G) \leq 3$, since graph is cubic. Clearly $\chi(G) \neq 1$. Also if $\chi(G) = 2$, then the graph would be bipartite, and hence its girth should be even. Therefore $\chi(G) = 3$.